# Handle rails route with GPS parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, routes

I'd like to create a route in my rails app to handle a gps-coordinate parameter. The intention is to find restaurants near the given position.

This is were I started:

`match "/restaurants/near/:lat/:lng(/:range)", :to => "restaurants#near", :as => "near", :constraints => {:range => /\d+/}`

It seems the router has problems with float parameters, an url like /restaurants/near/53.0123/10.5678 isn't recognized. Do you have a solution or best practice for handling GPS coordinates in rails urls?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this path ok for you?: `get '/restaurants/near' => 'restaurants#near', :as => :near_restaurants`. And to use it: `near_restaurants_path(:lat => 1.1, :lng => 2.2, :range => 10)`. The path generated would become `/restaurants/near?lat=1.1&lng=2.2&range=10`. The most important part is it is the same in the controller.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is caused because Rails try to use the "dots" for search for the format `(.:format)`
So, you can add some constraints to fix it, for example:

```
match "/restaurants/near/:lat/:lng(/:range)", :to => "restaurants#near", :as => "near", :constraints => {:lat => /\-?\d+(.\d+)?/, :lng => /\-?\d+(.\d+)?/ , :range => /\d+/}
```